# CKEDITOR - PHP Impossible to POST HTML Brut Code in my MYSQL Data Base - How to do this

Tags: php, html, post, mysqli, ckeditor

I've got a personnal site **which will never be online**.

I am using a Form with CKEDITOR Textarea.

I want PHP to Post the HTML Source Code generated by CKEDITOR in the Textarea in my MYSQL Database.

How to FORCE the PHP Code to POST HTML language in my data base ?

My Code :
http://alex69.dyndns.info/meridien/MyCode.doc

Comment: I don't see your </form> anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Use the `updateElement()` method to update the textarea if thats what you want to do.  But I think this is automatically handled by the ckeditor instance when the form is submitted by php.  Your ckeditor content will be in the id of the textarea itself on which you binded ckeditor when you post your form.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
alert( document.getElementById( 'editor1' ).value );  // The current editor data.
```

[CKEditor Docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#updateElement)